# Setter and Getters in Java

Tags: java, setter, getter

When I run this program, it returns:

> 00:00:00
>   00:00:00
>   00:00:00
>   00:00:00

What am I doing wrong and how can I get it to return the numbers I intended to return?

This is the code in my main class.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    tuna tunaObject1 = new tuna();
    tuna tunaObject2 = new tuna(5);
    tuna tunaObject3 = new tuna(5, 13);
    tuna tunaObject4 = new tuna(5, 13, 43);

    System.out.println(tunaObject1.toMilitary());
    System.out.println(tunaObject2.toMilitary());
    System.out.println(tunaObject3.toMilitary());
    System.out.println(tunaObject4.toMilitary());
}

}
```

This is my code in the class outside the main one.

```
public class tuna {
    private int hour;
    private int minute;
    private int second;

public tuna() {
    this(0, 0, 0);
}

public tuna(int h) {
    this(h, 0, 0);
}

public tuna(int h, int m) {
    this(h, m, 0);
}

public tuna(int h, int m, int s) {
    setTime(h, m, s);
}

public void setTime(int h, int m, int s) {
    setHour(h);
    setMinute(m);
    setSecond(s);
}

public void setHour(int h) {
    hour = ((hour >= 0 && hour < 24) ? hour:0);
}

public void setMinute(int m) {
    minute = ((minute >= 0 && minute < 60) ? minute:0);
}

public void setSecond(int s) {
    second = ((second >= 0 && second < 60) ? second:0);
}

public int getHour() {
    return hour;
}

public int getMinute() {
    return minute;
}

public int getSecond() {
    return second;
}

public String toMilitary() {
    return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", getHour(), getMinute(),  getSecond());
}

}
```

Comment: what is the expected result?

Comment: Your assign the instance fields back to them selves, `hour = ((hour >= 0 && hour < 24) ? hour:0);`, when `h` is the parameter

Comment: 00:00:00

05:00:00

05:13:00

05:13:43

Comment: You actually never really set anything; all parameters of your setters are just plainly ignored. Look carefully at your code...

Comment: You should be using `h` and not `hour`. Same issue occurs for `second` and `minute`

Comment: Ahh I see, silly me. Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: I would suggest following the java style of starting class names with a capital letter

Answer (score 3):

```
public void setHour(int h) {
    hour = ((hour >= 0 && hour < 24) ? hour:0);
}
```

should be

```
public void setHour(int h) {
    hour = ((h >= 0 && h < 24) ? h:0);
}
```

Likewise for other setters

Answer (score 3):

Look for example at your `setHour` method:

```
hour = ((hour >= 0 && hour < 24) ? hour:0);
```

Note that class members has default values, since `hour` is an `int`, it gets 0 as default value ([JLS 4.12.5. Initial Values of Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5)). So your method is equivalent to:

```
hour = ((0 >= 0 && 0 < 24) ? 0 : 0);
```

The same holds for other methods.

Additional notes:

- Debug your code - the debugger will help you to discover the reasons of bugs very quickly
- Follow the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) and rename your class to `Tuna`

After I described the problem, it's easy to fix it. Use `h` instead of `hour`, I'm sure you can handle this by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
public void setHour(int h) {
    hour = ((hour >= 0 && hour < 24) ? hour:0);
}
```

should be

```
public void setHour(int h) {
    hour = ((h >= 0 && h < 24) ? h:0);
}
```

Likewise, for others you would have to change. The problem is you have wrongly assigned the variables. Please look at the answer from @Maroun Maroun. He has clearly told you why it didn't work. Please follow Java conventions while writing code.

Answer (score 0):

please try these methods: The passing values have no effect on the actual fields due to which they are displaying default values.

```
public void setHour(int h) {
    hour = ((h >= 0 && h < 24) ? h : 0);
}

public void setMinute(int m) {
    minute = ((m >= 0 && m < 60) ? m : 0);
}

public void setSecond(int s) {
    second = ((s >= 0 && s < 60) ? s : 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming intended output is
00:00:00
05:00:00
05:13:00
05:13:43

you have to make changes in the tuna class

```
public void setHour(int h) {
        hour = ((hour >= 0 && hour < 24) ? h:0);
    }

    public void setMinute(int m) {
        minute = ((minute >= 0 && minute < 60) ? m:0);
    }

    public void setSecond(int s) {
        second = ((second >= 0 && second < 60) ? s:0);
    }
```

**Reason:**  In setter methods , value passed should be assigned to class property/attributes and here value passed is stored in variable "s" not in "second".